# Слитно или с дефисом? Буква «е» или «э»?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Трудный случай: как пишется слово «бл(е/э)к(-)лист»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре нет слова ***блек-лист***, но можно сравнить с похожим словом ***блек-джек*** (карточная игра). Вероятно, слово уже достаточно обрусело, так что формант "блэк" считается ненормированным.

Но на практике письма пока еще встречаются оба варианта (блек-джек и блэк-джек).

Грамота.ру объясняет похожий пример. Вопрос № 257232. Пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно сказать: Попробуйте свои силы в покер или *блэкджек*.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Корректно: играть в покер или **блек-джек**; попробовать силы в покере или блек-джеке.

По аналогии правильное написание: ***блек-лист.***